# How should I reconfigure venting when relocating laundry drains?

Tags: plumbing, basement, laundry

I am renovating the basement and need to reconfigure the laundry area. There is a main stack with upper floor bath fixtures all connected, then 2" vent pipe next to it in basement. Currently the washer and sink are connected to the vent pipe (tee, backflow preventer, wye).

I plan on moving the laundry sink to the opposite side of the washer, which will be approximately 8 feet from the current connections.

I'm wondering if I should cut out the existing connections to the vent stack, add a new tee to the soil stack, and tie into the vent above. Or, if I'm okay to continue using the vent stack as a drain for this application, cut the wye off the backflow preventer and run a new horizontal over to my sink. Due to the distance from the vent, I would need to still tie back in a vent above.

Please forgive my crude diagram, but I think it illustrates what I'm thinking. I'm in Canada, so I know some things are a little different up here.

[image: current]

[image]

Comment: I don't know Canadian code, but in general, a purely dry vent is far superior to a wet vent in terms of capacity, so I'd lean towards separating the functions when re-doing it.

Comment: There is a maximum distance that a trap can be from a vent, and for 2" pipe, I think its 8 feet.  That said, I never like to get close the maximum if there's another option.